Display image in classic SharePoint calendar and in Outlook
I've got a classic SharePoint calendar that many colleagues connect to their outlook to overlay with their personal calendars.
When I go to upload an image on the SharePoint calendar, I can see it in both the SP calendar and in outlook when I click on the event. However, all other staff just see the following on Sharepoint and Outlook:


Does this have to do with permission settings? Or does the calendar lack this functionality?
